# org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource

Tags: java, velocity

I am trying to create velocity template and send mail. I am getting error -  org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource 'template.vm'

I am using velocity1.7.jar and java 7. Please find the code below for reference.

```
VelocityContext velCtx = new VelocityContext();
velCtx.put("cepcnEmailBean", cepcnEmailBean);
VelocityEngine velEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
velEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
velEngine.init();
Template vtl = null;
vtl = velEngine.getTemplate("template.vm");
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter();
vtl.merge(velCtx, strWriter);
```

I am getting exception on line no 9 and file "template.vm" was there in the classpath. Please check and let me know if I want to fix anything.